# Can't get the right url_for static file in Flask locally

Tags: flask, static-files

I have a web server that can do what I need, but for the purpose of developing the app I want some of my static files to be served locally. 
For example, I have /Desktop/project_folder/static/jsons/example.json.
I try:

```
print(url_for('static', filename='jsons/example.json'))
/static/jsons/example.json
```

What I get is /static/jsons/example.json.

I try to set the static_path by:

```
app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='/Desktop/project_folder/static')
print(app.static_folder)
/Desktop/project_folder/static
url = url_for('static', filename='jsons/example.json')
print(url)
/static/jsons/example.json
```

I checked a few dozens similar questions here and they all suggest adjusting either static_folder or static_url_path but neither of those helps - I just start to get 404 errors on all other resources I have in my static folder. I also tried send_from_directory but what I get is werkzeug.wrappers.Response object and I can't get the data out of it.

UPDATE:
I try to load this json with:

```
json_loaded = json.load(requests.get(url).text)
```

And get an error: MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/static/jsons/example.json’: No schema supplied.

Comment: What is wrong with `/static/jsons/example.json`? Do you have multiple static folders?

Comment: I updated the question, I try to get this url’s content with requests, and get an error: MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/static/jsons/example.json’: No schema supplied.

Comment: I'm starting to get a feeling that it's still easier to just have some cdn to keep the static files and not bother with serving them via Flask at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell requests where the file lives. A path isn't enough. You also need to include a scheme and a domain, hostname, or IP address. Only the port is optional.

```
requests.get('http://example.com/path/to/file')
```

Since you are using `url_for` to generate the URL for you, you need to tell it to include this information for you.

```
url_for('static', filename='jsons/example.json', _external=True)
```